# What is difference between 2 sql queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 sql queries one of them work but the other gives error. Following query works well

```
select /*ordered*/ coupon_address.coupon,merchant_address.id  
from merchant_address, 
     coupon_address, 
     customers c  
WHERE merchant_address.id = coupon_address.merchant_address 
  and c.CUSTOMER_ID = 'temp1' 
  AND sdo_within_distance(c.cust_geo_location,merchant_address.store_geo_location,'distance = 1 unit=MILE') = 'TRUE';
```

But following query doesn't work and gives an error

```
select /*ordered*/ coupon_address.coupon,merchant_address.id  
from  coupon_address, 
      customers c 
  JOIN merchant_address ON merchant_address.id=coupon_address.merchant_address
 WHERE c.CUSTOMER_ID = 'temp1' 
   AND sdo_within_distance (c.cust_geo_location,merchant_address.store_geo_location, 'distance = 1 unit=MILE') = 'TRUE';
```

Error is

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "COUPON_ADDRESS"."MERCHANT_ADDRESS": invalid identifier

Comment: You are mixing the old, ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins with an explicit `JOIN` operator. Don't do that.

Comment: If you use the ANSI syntax, you have to use it for all the tables; the same way, if you decide to use the old Oracle join syntax ( and this is strongly discouraged), do it for all the tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean by mixing outdated joins with JOIN?

Comment: Include table definition

Answer (score 6):

Don't ever mix explicit and implicit join syntax together! They will always lead to confusion and errors :

```
select /*ordered*/ coupon_address.coupon,merchant_address.id
FROM coupon_address
JOIN merchant_address
  ON merchant_address.id=coupon_address.merchant_address
JOIN customers c ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = 'temp1'
WHERE  sdo_within_distance (c.cust_geo_location,
                            merchant_address.store_geo_location, 
                           'distance = 1 unit=MILE') = 'TRUE';
```

The reason it didn't work is the order that the parser evaluates the query. Probably the unknown column's table wasn't evaluated yet.

Comment: Would bet this does not solve the actual question and should go as comment instead. A comment that was already made.

Comment: This did work though I am not sure whats the problem with the join statement I have written in question.

Comment: The problem is the order that the optimizer evaluates the query. Probably the unknown column's table wasn't evaluated yet. @raju

Comment: @alfabravo On what? :)

Comment: It's because in your original query you attempted to inner join the customer table to the merchant_address table using ANSI syntax but the join condition is for a different table. It would probably work if you had `from customers, coupon_address inner join merchant_address on merchant_address.id = coupon_address.merchant_address`, although I wouldn't recommend it. Stick to one join syntax throughout your query and you'll not get confused.

Comment: btw the parser and the optimiser are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The `JOIN` has a higher precedence than the `,` in the `FROM` clause. `ON` is part of the `JOIN` so it only sees that which begin joined, including earlier joins.

So:

```
select /*ordered*/ coupon_address.coupon,merchant_address.id  
from  coupon_address, 
      customers c 
  JOIN merchant_address
    ON merchant_address.id=coupon_address.merchant_address
```

is in essence:

```
select /*ordered*/ coupon_address.coupon,merchant_address.id  
from  coupon_address, 
      (customers c 
  JOIN merchant_address
    ON merchant_address.id=coupon_address.merchant_address)
```

and `coupon_address` is not yet in scope.

As others have said, best to stick to one style of joins, either SQL-92 `join` keywords or the earlier commas in the `from` clause and join criteria in the `where` clause. I prefer the explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Wrong!  It is *not* best to stick to one type of `join`.  It is best to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sagi's answer is correct.  The reason your version doesn't work is because of the scoping rules around commas in the `FROM` clause.  Oh, did I mention:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Your `FROM` clause is evaluated as:

```
from coupon_address, 
     (customers c JOIN
      merchant_address
      ON merchant_address.id = coupon_address.merchant_address
     )
```

I think this makes it obvious why you are getting the error.